# include a php file in magento admin panel

Tags: php, file, magento, include

I am creating a module called "Web" in magento 1.7.2. Folder structure is like `app/code/local/Company/Web/` then Block, controllers, Model, etc, Helper. Again under `controllers` creating `Adminhtml` folder and `IndexController.php` file. Under `Adminhtml` folder `ProductController.php` file is there. I have another one file which is in my root folder called `reader.php` file. I want to include that file in my `ProductController.php` file. But unable to do so. I have tried by the following code:

```
$basePath = Mage::getRoot();
 include($basePath.'/reader.php');
```

Please help me how to include the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anybody is there?please help me.

Comment: Did you look at magento source before asking here?

Comment: Try move your file to `app` folder

Comment: why do you need to include it ? the way you want to do is not the proper if we follow magento standards and there is probably another way to do what you want.

Comment: Sorry for asking this stupid question. I got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mage::getRoot()` gives you the app folder. You should use `Mage::getBaseDir()` instead. That will give you your absolute base dir.